# Plus charge style in organic molecules

Tags: chemfig

I want to change the format of `\oplus` command but I can't change the style.
Style wanted :
[image: different style for "\oplus"]

To explain a little bit, I don't want the circle of \oplus to touch the + sign.

Help's appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the actual use case, but maybe just a `+` in a `circle` node?

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{[:30]-@{x}(-[:90])-[:330]}
\chemmove{
    \node[shift={(10pt,5pt)}, circle, draw, inner sep=0pt] (plus) at (x) {+};
    \node[anchor=west] at (plus.east) {$\neq\oplus$};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me !

Comment: @Tony Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem (checkmark symbol).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{-[:30]\charge{30:8pt[draw, circle]=$+$}{}(-[2])-[:-30]}
    \chemfig{-[:30]\charge{
        30:8pt[draw, circle]=$+$,
        30:8pt[anchor=west]=\phantom{+}$\neq\oplus$}{}(-[2])-[:-30]}
\end{document}
```

[image]